# Get/Set in java and reference

Tags: java

Get / Set methods are there to protect my class fields.

But since Java is working with reference my private fields are still getting exposed..

e.g.

```
private Date d;

Date getDate(){
  return d;
}

void setDate(Date inD){
//Checks for inD 
d = inD;
}


//Still the issue is 

getDate().setHours(xyz);
```

What is the correct approach? Because i dont want to change my Date without using setDate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Because i dont want to change my Date without using setDate.

Then you shouldn't return a reference to a mutable object in your `get` method. For example:

```
private Date d;

Date getDate() {
  // Return a reference to an independent copy of the original data
  return new Date(d.getTime());
}

void setDate(Date inD) {
    // Checks for inD 
    d = inD;
}
```

A better approach (IMO) would be to use immutable types for your fields - the [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) API is a much cleaner date/time library *and* it has plenty of immutable types.

Now that was just an example of course - in other cases you might want to return an immutable *view* on a mutable object (which you would usually avoid mutating yourself) in order to avoid having to copy a lot of data on each `get` call.

Comment: Can you explain "immutable view"? I am think in line of returning a const reference if that is possible. like public final Date getDate()

Comment: return new Date(d.getTime());  - Please explain this, I didnot understand, How can a get method helps in not changing the original value??

Comment: @sethi: No, there's no such concept as a "const reference" in Java. Using `final` on a method declaration means the method can't be overridden. For the "immutable view" I mean an object which delegates read-only access onto another object, but doesn't allow any mutation.

Comment: @gowtham: Well that returns an *equal* `Date` to the original, but it's an independent object.

Comment: @JonSkeet ya but how that helps in not changing the original value,It is get method, we use setter to set the value, I really cannot understand, Please explain

Comment: @gowtham with the new in get you have 2 objects with same value but not the same reference...so changing the object returned by the get function does the affect the class member.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am new to Java. Is it a common scenario where the caller understands that they cannot/shouldn't change the referring value

Comment: @sethi: That depends on the proficiency of the API developers, to be honest. It's the sort of thing that is normal within an *internal* API (but documented as such) - it's not the sort of thing I'd expect in a public API.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good approach for that which is called Defensive Copy,

```
Date getDate(){
   return new Date(d.getTime());
}
```

you'll get a copy of it and original one will have no affect

Answer (score 0):

Date is just an abomination since it is mutable. What you could do to make it safe, is to return a copy of the date. If that is modified, the original value is not changed.